# Does a proton oscillating at RF produce an EM field with a -E vector

Tags: electromagnetism

to clarify - FACT:  oscillating charges of sufficient frequency produce a propagating EM field. All communications is based on electron oscillation.

Question: IF a proton was oscillated at RF would it produce a EM field with -E relative to the E of an EM wave from an electron driven antenna.

Would the two waves cancel if they met, what effect would a proton induced EM wave have on electronic equipment?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an oscillating proton would produce electromagnetic waves. However, for the same driving force, the acceleration of an proton would be smaller than that of an electron by a factor of $m_e/m_p$.

Larmor's formula tells us that the total power radiated by an accelerated charge is proportional to the time average of the square of its acceleration (or the time average of the square of the second derivative of its dipole moment). So the radiated power from the proton would be a factor $(m_{e}/m_{p})^2$ smaller for the same driving force. The field strengths would be smaller by $m_{e}/m_p$.

If a proton and an electron were accelerated using the same Lorentz force - say for simplicity, a sinusoidally varying electric field, then the electromagnetic radiation they produced (i.e. scattered) would be $\pi$ out of phase if considered at the same displacement and at the same instant in time.

If you receive an electromagnetic wave without any other source of information, you cannot tell whether that wave has been produced by an accelerated proton or an accelerated electron.

Comment: thanks answered part of the question, an electric circuit would not be able to tell the difference. should the E vector of an EM wave be depicted in a diagram be 180 degrees to  that of an E vector in an EM wave of an electron.

Comment: @Peter Yes, that is what "$\pi$ out of phase" usually implies.

Comment: gotcha, I feel dumb now, I just never seen it in texts that way. I just "feel" there should be something different other than phase between a proton generated EM wave and an electron generated EM wave.

Comment: @Peter No. Just the phase and the factor of 1800 difference in amplitude for the same driving electric field. Of course there would perhaps be other differences if the E-field accelerates the electron to relativistic energies whilst the proton is still non-relativistic. That would make a good question!

Comment: like a proton and an electron are in the same EM field in the gamma region, they experience the same force but the proton stays classical and the electron goes all relativistic, what happens then? wow, I can't compose that in a coherent question but would sure like to.